# How to set the start point for reading an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

i have a large XML-Document (111 MB), and want to go to a special node (by index) very fast. The Document has about 1000000 nodes like this:

```
<Kt>
<PLZ>01067</PLZ>
<Ort>Dresden</Ort>
<OT>NULL</OT>
<Strasse>Potthoffstr.</Strasse>
</Kt>
```

I want to "jump", for example to the one millionth node in the document and start from this to read. All nodes behind of this must be ignore. I've tried it already with the XMLReader but these start always to read from the first node.

```
        int i = 0;//                    v-----------Index of the Node where I want to go!
        while (reader.Read() == (i < 1000000))
        {
            if (reader.Name == "PLZ")
            {
                textBox1.Text = reader.ReadString();
            }

            if (reader.Name == "Ort")
            {
                textBox2.Text = reader.ReadString();
            }

            if (reader.Name == "OT")
            {
                textBox3.Text = reader.ReadString();
            }

            if (reader.Name == "Strasse")
            {
                textBox4.Text = reader.ReadString();
                i++;
            }
```

This is how the structure of the XML-Document looks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Kt.xsd" generated="2014-10-21T18:20:30">
<Kt>
<PLZ>01...</PLZ>
<Ort>Dresden</Ort>
<OT>NULL</OT>
<Strasse>NULL</Strasse>
</Kt>
<Kt>
<PLZ>01067</PLZ>
<Ort>Dresden</Ort>
<OT>Innere Altstadt</OT>
<Strasse>Marienstr.</Strasse>
</Kt>
<Kt>
<PLZ>01067</PLZ>
<Ort>Dresden</Ort>
<OT>NULL</OT>
<Strasse>Potthoffstr.</Strasse>
</Kt>
```

**In other words: What are the possibilities to load a part of an large xml-file out without reading the complete file.**

Comment: Make a note of this downside to xml. It is always very convenient to use initially but for any decent quantity of data, a text based format will let you down.

Answer (score 6):

You will *have* to read all the data up to that point, because xml (in common with most text-based deserialization formats) does not lend itself to skipping data. `XmlReader` has some helper methods to assist with this, like `ReadToNextSibling` and `ReadToFollowing`. Basically, that's the best you'll do unless you pre-index the file (separately) with the byte offsets of various elements (say, every 100th or 1000th element). And doing *that* means you'd be working in fragment (rather than document) mode, and you'd need to be very careful about namespaces (particularly: aliases declared on the document root).

Basically, what you are doing seems *about right*, if we start with the premise of having a 111MB, multi-million-element xml file. Frankly, my advice would be *don't do that in the first place*. Xml is not a good choice for huge data, unless it is *purely* as a dead-drop, perhaps to be bulk-loaded again later. It does not allow for efficient random access.

Comment: @user3347346 (in reply to now-deleted comment) those are conflicting requirements; xml **is not suited** to the combination of "very fast", "random access" and "huge". If you need fast random access, bulk load it into a database *first*, and do the access against a correctly indexed database. Or at least: use a different file format that allows for skipping - almost certainly a binary format of some kind (I could suggest a couple, but they will not be xml in any way).

Comment: @user3347346 or at best: as I already mentioned, pre-index the xml file and accept the pain of alias resolution

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this often, then you're doing the wrong thing. The data should be in a database, or at the very least, stored in smaller chunks.

If you're not doing it often, then is it really a problem? I would expect it to be doable in 5 seconds or so.